# Using grep in exec() in c

Tags: c, linux, grep, exec

I am trying to make a function that gets the information about  the process that  executes it. Basically I have to execut `ps -ef` then filter the results with `grep (the pid of the process)`. The problem is that I have to do this using `exec`, it  would be quite easy with `ps -ef | grep pid`.
For the moment I am able to pass the result of `ps` to the parent process but I do not know how to put it into `grep`.

In this code I tried to put the output of `ps` as the `stdin` of `grep`, but quite frankly, I have no clue of what I am doing. Should I just take what I get from the pipe and pass it somehow to `grep`?

Here is the code:

```
    int main(){

        /*Variables*/
        int fd[2][2];
        int cpid[2];

        char spid[10];

        int maxbuf=10000;
        char buffer[maxbuf];

        char ch;

        int count;
/********************/
        sprintf(spid,"%d", getpid());
        printf("%s\n", spid);

        if(pipe(fd[0])==-1){
            perror("Pipe error");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        cpid[0]=fork();    
        switch(cpid[0]){
            case -1:
                perror("Fork error");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            case 0:
                if(pipe(fd[1])==-1){
                    perror("Pipe error");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
                cpid[1]=fork();
                switch(cpid[1]){
                    case -1:
                        perror("Fork error");
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                    case 0:


                        close(fd[1][0]);
                        close(1);
                        dup(fd[1][1]);
                        //sleep(1);
                        //wait(NULL);
                        execlp("ps","ps","-ef",(char *)0);
                        perror("Error in ps command");
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

                    default:
                        close(fd[1][1]);
                        close(0);
                        dup(fd[1][0]);

                        close(fd[0][0]);
                        close(1);
                        dup(fd[0][1]);
                        //sleep(1);
                        //wait(NULL);
                        execlp("grep","grep", spid, (char *)0);
                        perror("Error in grep command");
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
            default:
                for (count=0;read(fd[0][0], &ch,1)==1 && count<maxbuf; count++){
                    buffer[count]=ch;
                }

        }



        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

    }
```

What I get from this code does when executed is: it prints the number of the parent process and the freezes. If I use `pstree` with the pid of the process
I see `test───grep` which means if freezes on `grep` (correct me if I am wrong)
I know there are some crapy parts like the `buffer[maxbuff]`, but I want to focus on the `grep` issue.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: "Should I just what I get from the pipe and pass it somehow to grep?". Yes you should. Connect the stdout of `ps` to the stdin of `grep`.

Comment: That is what i think i have done

Comment: You are using too many pipes. You only need one pipe. The parent does not need to be a conduit. The ps process should write to one end of the pipe and the grep should read from the other end.

Comment: I am using 2 pipes, one to get the ps output to grep, then one to get the grep output to the first parent process. Is this wrong?

Comment: It's not wrong. But that wasn't what you stated in your question: "I do not know how to put it into grep". To "put it into grep" you only need one pipe. So you are now saying you also want to pass the grep result back to the top process (not just print out the whole result to the terminal)? We can't really re-code the whole thing for you (which it may well need). Can only answer *specific* questions.

Comment: The problem is not in the output of grep, it is in the input. What you suggested initially was already on the code and not working. I suggest we focus on the _specific_ question which is, how do I get the output of ps into grep and not on the number of pipes I am using.

Comment: @Ctx It is very similar, what I try to do is the other way around. In this post `grep` does not receive from the pipe (just sends), and that is exactly my problem.

Comment: @Nevado Replace `wc` in the linked post with your `grep`and the `grep` there with your `ps -ef` and you should be there

Comment: @Ctx I will try it right now and tell you the results, thank you man.

Comment: I used it in a little test and it works perfectly :) Thank you a lot.

Comment: Btw, I just realized my pipes code was fine, it freezes in the final for loop.